# When does find report a double forward slash in paths?

Tags: bash, find

```
~> find .m2/ -name com
.m2//repository/com
```

I'm not sure why I'm seeing a `//` in this path? Executed from bash on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a folder with forward slash in its name. You can replicate this sort of behaviour in OS X terminal with following commands:

```
mkdir -p test/"/test2"
find test
```

This works at least on OS X El Capitan...

But you are probably working with local Maven repository here, so I think it's weird that it would have double forward slash on repository path. Maybe it's some sort of bug...

EDIT:
Actually find on OS X appears to append results to what ever you have set as the path in the command. So because you had that forward slash in the directory when executing find, you got results with double forward slash...